Nginx-Traefik Reverse Proxy versus NGINX FastCGI Support
I am using docker-compose.yaml to define the services I need for my local development. Recently, I have added a new Traefik service to benefit from Domain Name Service Resolution capabilities that Traefik offers.
A typical Traefik service definition:
version: '3'

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.6.0"
    container_name: coolstuff_solutions_traefik
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--accesslog.filepath=/data/access.log"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.network=coolstuff-solutions"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.default.protocol=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`coolstuff.localhost`)"
    networks:
      coolstuff-solutions:
        aliases:
          - traefikversion: '3'

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.6.0"
    container_name: coolstuff_solutions_traefik
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--accesslog.filepath=/data/access.log"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.network=coolstuff-solutions"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.default.protocol=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=Host(`coolstuff.localhost`)"
    networks:
      coolstuff-solutions:
        aliases:
          - traefik 

Let us say, that I already had an NGINX service running to support my development attempts through a specified port; maybe designated through the docker-compose.yaml configuration file. In my case I already had an NGINX dedicated service:
nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: coolstuff_solutions_nginx
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www
      - ./sys/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
    networks:
      coolstuff-solutions:
        aliases:
          - nginx

It should be noted that the default.conf file, for NGINX, refers to the php-fpm service with fastcgi_pass app:9000;.
In its own right, NGINX is a Reverse Proxy capable by nature. However, I want to take advantage of the Traefik capabilities.
Is it possible for me to mix Traefix, NGINX, and PHP-FPM if I still want to make use of FastCGI?
Below is the docker-compose.yaml entry for the app container and its related Dockerfile and NGINX config.
#app service exposing API and any other pre-defined accessible endpoints
 app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: sys/php/Dockerfile
    image: coolstuff_solutions:app
    container_name: coolstuff_solutions_app
    env_file:
      - app/.env
    environment:
      APP_NAME: "CoolStuff Solutions"
    working_dir: /var/www
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www
      - ./app/var/:/var/www/var:rw
      - ./sys/php/default.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.default.protocol=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app.rule=Host(`app.coolstuff.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.app.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
      - "traefik.backend=app"
    networks:
      coolstuff-solutions:
        aliases:
          - app

#NGINX for PHP-FPM service
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}

# PHP-FPM Dockerfile

FROM php:8.2-fpm

ENV USER=www
ENV GROUP=www

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    git \
    curl \
    libldap2-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libgd-dev \
    zip \
    zlib1g-dev \
    librabbitmq-dev \
    unzip \
    ghostscript \
    fontconfig \
    graphviz

RUN pecl install amqp && docker-php-ext-enable amqp

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set timezone
RUN rm /etc/localtime \
    && ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Africa/Harare /etc/localtime \
    && "date"

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd intl

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

# Setup working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/

# Create User and Group
RUN groupadd -g 1000 ${GROUP} && useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g ${GROUP} ${USER}

# Grant Permissions
RUN chown -R ${USER} /var/www

# Select User
USER ${USER}

# Copy permission to selected user
COPY --chown=${USER}:${GROUP} . .

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]

In my view, there should be means to bind Traefik to NGINX such that we can benefit from FastCGI but the fact that we speaking to two Proxy Server products, it seems like something is not adding up.

Sure you can use Traefik as first reverse proxy and proxy/forward requests to any target service, even another proxy or web-server. Either you add labels to your nginx for Traefik Docker configuration discovery via providers.docker, or you setup the Traefik routers/services manually in a dynamic config file, loaded via providers.file in Traefik static config.
Personally I prefer to run PHP in a Docker image with included web-server (like php:<version>-apache), I assume its already perfectly configured and I don't need to mess with FPM and Fast-CGI.
Please not that Traefik v2.6 was released beginning of January 2022, make sure to update to a latest v2 or even new v3.
